# Very large paper height in Microsoft Office Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Is it possible to set the paper height to infinity or a very large value in Microsoft Office Word?
How I can do this?

Comment: I get the feeling this is going to turn out to be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) Would you like to explain your reasoning for this requirement?

Comment: How large did you use? The maximum paper size for a document in any version of Word -- PC or Mac -- is 22"x22".

Comment: On behalf of all print shop techs: please please please do not design a poster or mural using Word. Use InDesign, Illustrator, Freehand or some other graphics package instead

Answer (score 1):

The maximum paper size limit is `22" x 22" (55.88cm x 55.88cm)` as described in [Operating parameter limitations and specifications in Word](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/operating-parameter-limitation). You can't go above that.

From [Printing Very Large Paper Sizes](https://word.tips.net/T001026_Printing_Very_Large_Paper_Sizes.html):

> Word is hard-coded to permit document widths and heights as small as .1 inches and as large as 22 inches. Thus, the largest page area you can define in Word is 22 inches by 22 inches. This is an absolute limit. If you need to print to larger paper, then you will need to use a different program, such as a desktop publishing program.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have an arbitrarily large page in Word, but you can in
compatible products.

For example, the page size limit for LibreOffice Writer is 3x3 meters,
and 10 meters length in web layout.

If this is not enough, there are other
[Microsoft Word Alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-word/)
that would have other limits.

Comment: You can set up a gigantic Word document in LibreOffice Writer and then open and edit it in Word.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to make a white space work area to do something like use columns or tables to do comparison or troubleshooting.  That's why I want to do what you describe in any case.  Acknowledging Word's hard coded restriction on paper size, this is a work around to accomplish your probable goal.  Create the custom size paper of 22x22 inches.  Set the font size to 3 or so, and the zoom to another of Microsoft's "we know better than you what you need to do" limitation - Zoom = 500.  This will give you the white space document to do what you are looking for.  Obviously you can't print this, but since you wanted an infinite size, you never wanted it to be a printable document in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can, by editing the HTML source code in Notepad, after saving your Word document to HTML. Find the page size in the HTML header, and change it to any size you like. Save the HTML, open it in Word, and bang -- there is your Word document with a giant paper size, that now can be saved as DOCX.

Edit: used to work at some stage, but doesn't anymore unfortunately.